# What can I do about a user who is bullying?

Tags: discussion, users, abuse

I posted a question today on SO which was pretty simple. A user with over 16k points responded but had missed one of the key requirements I had mentioned. I commented that he had missed something and also updated my question to better illustrate what I was looking for.

The user then down-voted my question, began a rant, voted to close it and clearly found others to help him finalize closing it.

I then posted another question on SO and it became immediately closed and down-voted even after other users attempted to answer (and successfully answered) it.

So, I am being bullied here. What can I / should I do about it?

The first question was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432104/jquery-wrap-div-around-time-ranges

Second was: [Sense a time range in a text string, using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432968/sense-a-time-range-in-a-text-string-using-jquery#comment15083048_11432968)

Comment: Can you link to the question?

Comment: I don't know how [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432104/jquery-wrap-div-around-time-ranges) is bullying if you did change requirements. A mod closed the question; the other user just voted as well

Comment: I added links to my questions

Comment: @simchona - I didn't change requirements, just example code.

Comment: Your second question is clear "gimme teh codez". It would likely have been downvoted anyway.

Comment: Your second question was justifiably closed. Similar questions withing similar tags will also likely attract the same active users within those tags. I see no evidence of you being bullied here.

Comment: Unless there have been comments that got deleted, I really dont' think this is bullying.

Comment: I would have closed the second one as an exact duplicate of the first one.

Comment: @phirschybar - You aren't being bullied, you're being down-voted. There's a difference.

Comment: Also note there is a difference between being down-voted and having your question being voted to close. They don't mean the same thing and just because someone voted to close your question doesn't mean they are also one of the several who down-voted you.

Answer (score 27):

I assume you are reffering to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432104/jquery-wrap-div-around-time-ranges), followed by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432968/sense-a-time-range-in-a-text-string-using-jquery).

The first question was closed for good reason. As the comment by Kev states:

> We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself
>   rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for
>   you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some
>   effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and
>   flag to re-open. Thanks.

You then posted another question (a slightly reduced version of the original question by the look of it), but you failed to take on board the comments made on your previous question. You still just asked for a solution, and didn't demonstrate any attempt to solve the problem yourself.

You are not being bullied, you're just being guided towards asking better questions.

Comment: +1 for that last line.  One should always try to learn from their experiences.